# LSOpenURLsWithRole fails when opening App from command line

Tags: macos

I'm getting the below error when opening an .app from the Application folder.

```
open /Applications/Spark.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Spark.app
```

Comment: I've seen such errors in 2 situations -- either when the program is not compatible with the OS (but from what I saw at Macupdate, Spark seems to work up to Lion) or when the program is not installed correctly, e.g. the .dmg was corrupted or not expanded correctly or when the .app it was dragged to Dock before putting somewhere else.

Comment: @lipincho - what is Dock ? Actually i build the code in windows xp and but it is compatible to MAC, and dropped in applications folder and invoked from command prompt. Please can you help on this.

Comment: Dock: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2474; the place (usually at the bottom of the screen, sometimes on the side, from which one can star programs)